# Aligned memory allocation

Tags: c, malloc

I have the following assignment:

> Write a function in C that allocates block of memory and returns a pointer to the start of the memory under these conditions:
>
> 1. All addresses in the block are divisible by 32
> 2. Allocated at least the number of the bytes required
> 3. Every cell in the block is initialized to zero
> 4. No global variants, minimum complexity
>
> Write another function that also releases the memory that you allocated. (You know that the aforesaid memory was allocated by the first function that you just wrote ).

Here is a debugging temporary solution:

"aligned_malloc.h":

```
#ifndef  __ALIGNED_MALLOC_H__
#define  __ALIGNED_MALLOC_H__

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>

#define ALIGNMENT 16

#if ALIGNMENT > 255
#error "This 'void *aligned_malloc(size_t size)' function can only handle alignment < 256"
#endif

#if ALIGNMENT < 0
#error "This 'void *aligned_malloc(size_t size)' function can only handle a non negative alignment"
#endif

void* aligned_malloc(size_t size);
void aligned_free(void *aligned_p);

#endif /* __ALIGNED_MALLOC_H__ */
```

"alligned_malloc.c":

```
#include "aligned_malloc.h"

#undef  DEBUG
#define DEBUG 1

int main()
{
    size_t size = 0;
    void *memblk = NULL;

    do while (size > 0 )
    {
        printf("\nPlease enter in bytes the memory block size you want to allocate (0 to exit): ");
        scanf("%d", &size);
        memblk = aligned_malloc(size);

        #ifdef     DEBUG
            printf("%s[%d]: memblk = 0x%x\n", __FUNCTION__, __LINE__, memblk);
        #endif  /* DEBUG */

    }

    if (memblk != NULL)
        aligned_free(memblk);

    return 0;
}

void *aligned_malloc(size_t size)
{
    int i = 0;
    void* memblk = malloc(size + ALIGNMENT);
    printf ("\n%ld",(long)memblk);

    //offset is the start address of memblk (long=8digit) modulo the ALIGNMENT
    unsigned char offset = ALIGNMENT - ((long)memblk % ALIGNMENT);
    printf ("\n%d",offset);

    if (memblk == NULL)
        return NULL;
    /* O/W: */  
    #ifdef     DEBUG
    printf("%s[%d]: memblk = 0x%x\n", __FUNCTION__, __LINE__, memblk);
    #endif  /* DEBUG */
    for (i = offset; i < size + ALIGNMENT; i++) 
    {
        printf("%02d: %08d\n", i, memblk+i);
        memblk[i] = 0;
    }

    *(memblk + offset - 1) = offset;

    return (void*)(memblk + offset);
}

void aligned_free(void *aligned_p)
{
    unsigned char offset = (unsigned char)(*((unsigned char *)aligned_p-1));
    #ifdef     DEBUG
    printf("%s[%d]: offset = %d\n", __FUNCTION__, __LINE__, offset);
    printf("%s[%d]: aligned_p-1 = 0x%x\n", __FUNCTION__, __LINE__, (unsigned char *)aligned_p-1);
    printf("%s[%d]: aligned_p-offset = 0x%x\n", __FUNCTION__, __LINE__, aligned_p-offset);
    #endif  /* DEBUG */
    free(aligned_p-offset);
}
```

Now I have several problems here:

1. There is a compilation error in `main()`
2. I cannot catch how to use `calloc` instead of `malloc`
3. If I use the `void*` is there an option to cast it to 32 bytes chunks?

Comment: It might help if you tell people what the compilation error is. ALso what do you mean "cast it to 32 byte chunks"?

Comment: Well, I don't know the answer, but thanks for being honest in saying that this is homework. Usually people will just post the question and expect StackOverflow people to do it for them :)

Comment: `printf ("\n%ld",(long)memblk);` For printing pointers you should use `%p` specifier. Casting to `long` is not safe

Answer (score 2):

Your code is doing the right thing: you're working out how many bytes to skip before the aligned block and recording the number in the byte before the block begins. You've got a couple of basic problems:

In C you have either a `do { ... } while(cond)` loop or a `while(cond) { ... }` loop, but you've confused the two. Your do while syntax isn't legal, looks like you just want a while loop.

You can't do pointer arithmetic on a void* pointer because void has no size. Compute your new address either as a long: `((long)memblk+offset)` or as a pointer to a type that is a single byte in size (like a char). At the moment the addition is on a void* type giving your other compile error.

Guessing what compile errors you are seeing from the code is rather tricky - in future it would be easier if you post the errors that you see as well.

Comment: I think the OP wants a `do .. while`. `size` is initialized to zero at the top, so the loop won't execute at all if it is just a `while`.

Comment: please don't cast a pointer to `long`, `long` and pointers are not guaranteed to have the same width. Then also don't use signed arithmetic on pointer values if you don't need to. `uintptr_t` is probably the right thing (99% of the cases, I'd guess), or if you insist to have a signed type use `intptr_t`.

Answer (score 0):

Your do-while syntax is wrong. Should be:

```
do
{
   /* stuff to do */
} while(xxx);
```

Regarding `calloc`, it takes (1) the number of "things" you want to allocate, and (2) the size of each thing. It returns a zeroed block of memory with space to hold that number of things.

I don't understand the bit about casting void* to 32 bit chunks.

Answer (score 0):

My fault SoRRy :-|

Only the returning adresses should be divisble by 32 i.e. 100B -> 64...164
The ALIGNMENT should be set to 32 at the header file and here is a working code:

```
#include "aligned_malloc.h"

#undef  DEBUG
#define DEBUG 1

int main(void)
{
  size_t size = 0;
  void *res = NULL;

  printf("\nPlease enter size: ");
  scanf("%d", &size);

  while (size > 0) {

    res = aligned_malloc(size);

#ifdef     DEBUG
    printf("%s[%d]: res = 0x%x\n", __FUNCTION__, __LINE__, res);
#endif  /* DEBUG */

    if (res != NULL)
      aligned_free(res);

    printf("\nPlease enter size again (enter 0 to quit): ");
    scanf("%d", &size);
  }

  return 0;
}

void *aligned_malloc(size_t size)
{
  int i = 0;
  long *res = malloc(size + ALIGNMENT);
  unsigned char offset = ALIGNMENT - ((long)res % ALIGNMENT);

  if (res == NULL)
    return NULL;
  /* O/W: */  
#ifdef     DEBUG
  printf("%s[%d]: res = 0x%x\n", __FUNCTION__, __LINE__, res);
#endif  /* DEBUG */
  for (i = offset; i < size + ALIGNMENT; i++) {
      printf("%02d: %08d\n", i, res+i);
      res[i] = 0;
  }

  *(res + offset - 1) = offset;

  return (void*)(res + offset + 1);
}

void aligned_free(void *aligned_p)
{
  unsigned char offset = (unsigned char)(*((unsigned char *)aligned_p-1));
#ifdef     DEBUG
  printf("%s[%d]: offset = %d\n", __FUNCTION__, __LINE__, offset);
  printf("%s[%d]: aligned_p-1 = 0x%x\n", __FUNCTION__, __LINE__, (unsigned char *)aligned_p-1);
  printf("%s[%d]: aligned_p-offset = 0x%x\n", __FUNCTION__, __LINE__, aligned_p-offset);
#endif  /* DEBUG */
  free(aligned_p-offset);
}
```

PS I don't really know if it is possible to get 32B chunks...
THNX